# Chrome realod images after every postback - updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, updatepanel

I have a page that's running with an UpdatePanel inside.
When i click in a button it does it normal postback and loads a grid.

The problem is: The images inside the grid and other images inside the updatepanel are 
"refreshing". The content(HTML/Plain text) is not....So it look's so weird to see the images reloading them self and the text being static.

I am using updateMode = 'Always'. But already tried with mode = 'Conditional' and didn't worked.

I've tested on IE 8 and 9 and it looks fine, no image is reloading.Only on chrome.

Any ideas of what it could be?

Comment: I have just tested this and, strangely, I have the same behaviour as you when I use the application in localhost, but in the production server the images are not reloaded on every partial postback. Have you checked this? No idea of why this is happening though

Comment: Yeah aleafonso, you are correct.

I've tested on IIS production server and it works fine.

I guess it have to do with the way IIS respond to the GET of an image.
It returns HTTP 304(not modified) after images loading the first time....that's probably making some difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah aleafonso, you are correct. 
I've tested on IIS production server and it works fine. I guess it have to do with the way IIS respond to the GET of an image. It returns HTTP 304(not modified) after images loading the first time....that's probably making some difference.

Comment: nope..we just ignored the behaviour on dev machines. On test and production its OK beacuse IIS makes the correct cache. By the way, you could try looking for some configuration on the local IIS that could change the cache thing. Look for the HTTP 304 or something like that that you migth get the answer....